# Is there any feasible way to work with live electrical wiring?

Tags: electrical

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install an electrical outlet on a live circuit?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/6928/how-do-i-install-an-electrical-outlet-on-a-live-circuit)

I remember back in my college days, having a badly damaged outlet plug on a built-in dresser/vanity right above my bed (the face had cracked away exposing the metal contacts for the hot and ground). My solution, not needing the plug at all, was simply to tape over it. However, had I put in a maintenance request, let's assume for a second that the most granular breaker circuit available would still shut down half the dorm floor and so it normally wouldn't be done.

How then would an electrician or maintenance guy attempt to replace the outlet while keeping it live? Obviously the average joe working on his home wiring should ALWAYS kill the breaker (because otherwise he can kill himself), but if you HAD to work on a live circuit, as a professional electrician, how would you prepare/protect yourself?

Comment: If you were an electrician, you would certainly turn off the breaker.

Comment: See also [How do I take a live wire off of a two way switch?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/3323/33)

Comment: The electrician in your example should be fired if he's afraid to power off a dorm floor. Unplanned power outages happen all the time, its merely inconvenient.

Forget the electrician's safety, what happens when the roommate barges in and stumbles over the electrician handling live wires?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Professional electricians work on live circuits all the time. They don't shut down the powergrid when they have to climb a telephone pole. ;)

The key with working with ANY electricity is to make sure you aren't grounded and providing a path for the current. This typically involves using all sorts of various insulators...rubber gloves...rubber shoes...not using metal tools, not being on a metal ladder, etc, etc.

But yea, whenever possible, kill the power first.

Comment: Electricians do; from time to time, work on live circuits. However, they have both training and experience in doing so. If you are not an electrician, you should **Never** work on a live circuit.

Comment: And those electricians understand the risks and are aware that they're not doing something "safe".  There are many dangerous jobs out there and linesman is certainly one of them.

Comment: yes, yes. Agreed wholeheartedly. It should go without saying, but just in case: DO NOT TRY THIS AT HOME.

Comment: Like [this guy](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9tzga6qAaBA)?

Comment: Remember, there are no tools that have a voltage rating for working on live circuits.  Even though some insulated tools have a 1000v rating, the fine print says do not use on live circuits.

Comment: @Doresoom:  I love that vid. i actually know a couple of guys that build High Tension 64K and higher lines.  Way cool.

Comment: The busbar system used in commerical buildings is designed so that work can be done on it without powering down large fractions of a building. Even so, electricians still have safe-working practices like one hand at a time at the box. But consumer-level hardware doesn't have that design element.

Comment: "Bonding on" is one of the things on my bucket list that I'll probably never get to do.

Answer (score 5):

If you have to ask the question you have no business messing around with a live circuit.

Answer (score 4):

With one hand in your pocket.

But really, ***don't***.

Comment: And the other one smoking a cigarette.

Comment: (only) "One hand in the box."

Answer (score 2):

There are a variety of insulated tools available for when working on live circuits.  For example, here's a screwdriver insulated for 1000v, meaning, you will not get electrocuted through the  tool.

[image: Klein insulated screwdriver]

The guys working the hydro poles have all sorts of gear rated for much higher voltages that can make contact with the lives wires while keeping the user safe.  Even then it is still risky.

There is also the concept of a [Faraday Cage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage) that is used in the field. For example, when working on hydro lines from a helicopter.

As others have said, avoid it at all costs especially if you are not a professional.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of good advise from previous answers. I've been working electrical for over 40 years and often don't take my own advise about not working on hot wires and devices. I am always ultra careful not to put myself in a position to complete a circuit or a path to ground. I have to admit however, I have taken dozens of "zingers" across my fingers and hand and have managed to destroy a lot of expensive Klien Tools. YIKES that smarts! But then no one ever accused me of being a real smart person, so take it from someone that has done everything wrong a few times............So as I say, not as I do......Turn off the breaker!!!!!!